# C# Binary Reader

Tags: c#, binaryreader

I'm making an encryption program and need to save the encrypted password to a file using the  binary reader and writer. When i try and read the data out all I get is a number. What did I do wrong?

```
 public static string readData(string fileName)
    {
        string data;

        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fStream))
        {
            data = reader.Read().ToString();
        }

        return data;   
    }
```

And the writer

```
 public static void writeData(string fileName, string data)
 {

  using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open (fileName, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            writer.Write(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the documentation for `BinaryReader.Read()` tell you?

Comment: Please tell me this is a learning exercise and not for use in any type of production system.

Comment: This is a learning exersize. I'm a hobbyist as well, newer to c#. Please tell me what's so bad about what I coded. @TomStudee

Comment: @user3453481 Nothing bad at all, and no offense. Even most experienced programmers shouldn't be rolling encryption software from scratch. It's a very specialized area. But, learning is always encouraged.

Comment: Oh ok, and yes I had to look up examples of encryption coding, as the algorithims can get very complex. This is just a quick program I'm making for fun that could hold my passwords and encrypt them. Should I be using a different way to save the data instead of into a binary file?

Comment: If it's an encrypted password (i.e. a series of bytes), then why does your code work with `string`s (series of characters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reader.ReadString()` instead.

```
data = reader.ReadString();
```

The [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493z3f6h.aspx) method reads the next character and returns the corresponding integer value of it as you can see in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493z3f6h.aspx).basically, you have written a `string` to your file in binary format, so you need to read it back.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are calling the `Read` method that returns a single integer.¨

You want to do [`ReadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Most likely he doesn't want. After all how fits a string together with reading and writing _binary_ data?

Comment: Well he did say he was writing the password to a file using `WriteString`, so `ReadString` will be fine for reading it back. (I actually started the answer with `ReadBytes`, but then went back and read the question again).